# URL rewrite in conjunction with server redirect

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use URL rewrite with IIS7 to make **mydomain.com/home/default.aspx** look like **mydomain.com**.  Additionally, the original structure of the site has the root **default.aspx** redirecting to **mydomain.com/home/default.aspx**.

Thus, visits to **mydomain.com** would redirect to **mydomain.com/home/default.aspx** while showing only **mydomain.com** in the web browser address bar.

Can someone help me with the Inbound and Outbound rules to make this happen?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried something? Do you want anything coming to `mydomain.com` being rewritten to `mydomain.com/home/`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly Well, I'm quite new to this but I have tried several things. The page I need to display is mydomain.com/home/default.aspx but what I want to show in the address bar is just mydomain.com.

Comment: You want all your urls to be rewritten or only the home page?

Comment: @cheesemacfly Only the home page.

Comment: So what you want is when someone hits `mydomain.com` the url is rewritten to `mydomain.com/home/default.aspx`? What if the user hits `mydomain.com/about`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly Well, currently, when someone hits mydomain.com they are redirected via code behind to the actual homepage at mydomain.com/home/default.aspx.  But instead of mydomain.com/home/default.aspx showing in the address bar, I want to show only mydomain.com.  I would handle that about page differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the iis manager (`inetmgr`), select your website -> double click on `URL rewrite`.
You then have to click on the right on `Add Rule(s)...` and choose `Blank Rule`.
Fill up the fields with the following values:
[image: Rewrite rule]

This rule will match `mydomain.com` or `mydomain.com/` and rewrite it to `mydomain.com/home/default.aspx`.

This will produce the following rule in your `web.config`:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^/?$" negate="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="home/default.aspx" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I now have a better understanding of how this works. I had to remove my server redirect via code and then what you provided worked great.